# Contact form - ajax, wp_mail

Tags: ajax, wp-mail

I'm trying to create a simple contact form using jQuery to validate the form and AJAX to pass it to PHP and WP `wp_mail()` to send it.

I have a simple form like this.

```
    <form role="form">
        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Name</label>
            <input type="text" id="name" class="form-control" name" />
        </div>

        <div class="form-group">
            <label class="">Email</label>
            <input type="text" id="email" class="form-control" name="email" />
        </div>

        <?php wp_nonce_field( 'atex_php', 'atex_nonce' ); ?>

        <button class="submit">Submit</button>

    </form>
```

The jQuery function to validate the inputs and send to PHP:

```
//IsEmail and fadeOut functions aren't shown

    $atj(function(){
      $atj('submit').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        if(verfiyFields()) {

          $atj.post({
            data : {
              action : "request",
              firstName : $atj("#name").val(), 
              email : $atj("#email").val(), 
            }
          })
        }
      });
    })

    //Verfiy 
    function verfiyFields() {
      var flag = true;
      var name =  $atj('#name');
      var email = $atj('#email');

      if(name.val().indexOf(' ') === -1 ){
        name.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter name, first space last</p>');
        fadeOut();
        flag = false;
      }
      if(!IsEmail(email.val())){
        email.parent().prepend('<p class="form-error">Please enter valid email address</p>');
        fadeOut();
        flag = false;
      }
      return flag;
    }
```

And the the PHP in the `functions.php`:

```
    add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_request', 'my_action_callback' );
    function my_action_callback() {

        if ( isset( $_POST['atex_nonce'] ) && wp_verify_nonce( $_POST['atex_nonce'], 'atex_php' ) ) {
            $name = $_POST['firstName'];
            $email = $_POST['email'];

            $send_to = me@test.co.uk;

            $subject = 'Request from'. $name;

            $success = wp_mail($send_to, $subject, $message);

            if($success){
                return true;
            }else{
                return false;
            }

        }   
    }
```

I'm getting a `404 Not Found` for `[object%20Object]` in the Network tab of chrome dev tools when the submit is clicked.

How can I get this to work

Comment: Validating via JS only. No checks on user provided data. You will so get hacked... You might want to look at the [`esc_*()`](http://queryposts.com/?s=esc_) functions in core and [`filter_var()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.filter-var.php) and its `_array()` counterpart in PHP.

Answer (score 1):

From quick look at your code you seem to be omitting *where* you are submitting request to. By default it is just current page, which isn't typically equipped to receive the request.

Since you are using `wp_ajax_` hook you need to point request at `admin-ajax.php` endpoint. On admin side the URL is provided in `ajaxurl` JS variable, on front end side you would need to provide it to your code yourself.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rarst - do you know of any tutorials of information that explains how to do this, I can't seem to find any and I'm going round in circles

Comment: [AJAX in Plugins](http://codex.wordpress.org/AJAX_in_Plugins) in Codex would be a start.

Comment: Read that but still can't work it out

Comment: [Even more on AJAX](http://www.wptherightway.org/en/javascript/README.html#ajax)

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, you forgot to mention the destination of the request, and you are also missing ajaxurl (since you are using wp_ajax).

Another, more simple solution would be to create a php file to handle the request (ex: process-request.php), then to specify the url of this file in the ajax object before you submit your request. This solution is less "WordPress Compliant", but slightly more easy to do.